# Open Notepad++ from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, notepad++

How can I open up a file in Notepad++ from the Powershell command line?

Comment: @martineau: Actually this question is quite helpful for opening any file in Notepad++ from PowerShell. Just sayin..

Comment: Can we just edit this canonical question to not be Python specific? It has nothing to do with python...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Inside PowerShell I can simply use the start and get general results

to open a python file with notepad++ here is what I did.

```
Start notepad++ ex1.py
```

this will start notepad++ and load the file  ex1.py assuming you are in the same directory as the .py file. You can change that by adding the full path name

```
start notepad++ c:\users\you\desktop\files\ex1.py
```

Comment: In the greater scope `Start` opens any `.exe` program with any argument.

Comment: Any idea how to pipe it if the file is too big? I tried: `Get-Content "ids_2020-02-01.jsonl" -Tail 100 | Start notepad++` to no avail

Comment: You can open a directory as workspace using `notepad++ -openFoldersAsWorkspace .` (This will open the current directory as workspace.. Replace `.` with the path to the another directory if you want)

Answer (score 6):

Because the default path contains spaces, you have to quote the path to the exe. However because PowerShell is also a scripting language.  A string by itself is simply evaluated as a string e.g.:

```
C:\ PS> 'Hello world'
Hello world
```

So you have to tell PowerShell you want to invoke the command that is named by the string.  For that you use the call operator `&` e.g.:

```
C:\ PS> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'
```

or if notepad++ is in your path:

```
  C:\ PS> notepad++
```

or if you're in the same dir as the exe:

```
  C:\ PS> .\notepad++
```

Comment: ALright. Say I have some py files in a directory. How can I open them in Notepad++ from PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

To open Notepad++ with and create a new empty file in the current path

```
start notepad++ newFile.txt
```

To open Notepad++ with an existing file

```
start notepad++ apples.txt
```

To specify the path and open multiple files

```
start notepad++ fruits/apples.txt, fruits/oranges.txt, package.json
```

Answer (score 2):

To extrapolate on the previous answers and tie them up in a tidy bow:
If you want to open a file with spaces in the path or name:

```
. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' 'C:\Temp\File With Spaces.txt'
```

or

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' 'C:\Temp\File With Spaces.txt'
```

It can also be set it as an alias:

```
Set-Alias -Value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -Name 'NotePad'
$FileWithSpaces = 'C:\T e m p\File With Spaces.txt'
NotePad $FileWithSpaces
```

The top line here can be copied into (one of) your $Profile .ps1 file(s) so you don't need to keep using Set-Alias in every new PS instance.

Comment: What if I have a filename in $variable? It doesn't seem to work the same way

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but this may go some way to answer it.

$FileWithSpaces = 'C:\Temp\File With'        
$Spaces = ' Spaces.txt'
. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' $FileWithSpaces$Spaces

Answer (score 2):

Edit your profile and add an alias

```
Set-Alias -name 'npp' -value 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'
```

Then:

npp c:\temp\test.txt

Edit your profile:

npp $profile

etc

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found a bit of a workaround, quite by accident, and it is extremely straightforward.  If you install and maintain Notepad++ via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) (think apt-get for Windows, but built on top of NuGet), then you get a shim that can be invoked from the command line.

```
cinst notepad++
```

And even if you already have an existing installation of Notepad, you can still "install" it from Chocolatey, and it will pull in the existing installation and maintain it.

I use Chocolatey for as much as I possibly can, because you can update everything in one fell swoop.

After that, editing things from PowerShell is a snap.  Like my PowerShell profile:

```
notepad++ $PROFILE
```

Hope this helps someone, or several someones!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to start Notepad++ with a file as an argument, and open as admin. I wanted to open one of the PowerShell profiles. I had to use the following command variation:

```
start-process -Verb runas -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"  "`"$($PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts)`""
```

All the other variations didn't work, I think due to a space in the path of the file to be opened. So, you must escape the `"` as:

```
"He said `"This is fun.`""
```